# how to compile multiple projects in VS2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, project

I am learning design pattern following Mark Joshi's "Designs patterns and derivatives pricing". Here is all the code in his book:
http://www.markjoshi.com/design/
There are several projects have 'main' in 'mains' folder. I want to compile all of them together, without selecting every related files in each project. Any smart way for doing so in VS2008?

Answer (score 0):

VS itself does not provide such capabilities. Especially, since there is no explicit dependencies specified in any way except comments stating these. However you could create a script in your favorite scripting language, that would check `.cpp` files for dependencies and try to invoke compiler with proper arguments.

Following powershell script manages to compile almost all projects (some fail with linker errors and I have no intent to figure out the cause)

```
mkdir obj

$compilerPath = "cl.exe"

$projects = gci mains\*.cpp

foreach ($pm in $projects)
{
    Write-Output $pm.Name;

    $cppFiles = Get-Content $pm | Select-String "[\d\w]+\.cpp" | foreach-object {"source\" + $_.Matches[0].Value} | Select-String $pm.Name -NotMatch -SimpleMatch

    $cppFiles = @("mains\$($pm.Name)") + $cppFiles;

    & $compilerPath $cppFiles /I .\include\ /EHsc /Fo.\obj\
}
```

Script assumes that it is run from the directory that contains `include`, `mains` and `source` subdirectories. It should be run from `VS tools command prompt` (in order to have building environment properly set up).

Comment: Sheesh, that's some necro-bump. Well, let it stay anyway :)